# Cargo release binary size is larger in ArchLinux than in Fedora 36

Tags: rust, build, release, rust-cargo, filesize

I noticed that the release binary file is extremely larger in ArchLinux than in Fedora.
I was wondering what this huge difference was due to, though?

---

The size of the binary file in **ArchLinux** is:

```bash
$ cargo clean
$ cargo build --release
$ du -h target/release/ks_trace
3,7M    target/release/ks_trace
```

But in **Fedora 36** (*toolbox container*) is just:

```bash
$ cargo clean
$ toolbox run cargo build --release # on Fedora 36 container
$ du -h target/release/ks_trace
420K    target/release/ks_trace
```

> **P.S.** Adding some optimization rules to the `Cargo.toml` file can still decrease the binary file size to ~200kb in both OS.

---

**EDIT** It is strange that the output of `cargo bloat --release` (*as recommended*) returns, in **ArchLinux**:

```bash
$ cargo bloat --release
File  .text     Size           Crate Name
0.5%   8.6%  19.8KiB             std addr2line::ResDwarf<R>::parse
0.5%   7.9%  18.2KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::resolve::{{closure}}
0.3%   4.2%   9.6KiB             std addr2line::ResUnit<R>::parse_lines
0.2%   3.7%   8.5KiB             std miniz_oxide::inflate::core::decompress
0.2%   2.6%   5.9KiB             std gimli::read::abbrev::Abbreviations::insert
0.1%   1.9%   4.5KiB             std gimli::read::unit::parse_attribute
0.1%   1.7%   4.0KiB             std addr2line::function::Function<R>::parse_children
0.1%   1.7%   3.9KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::Context::new
0.1%   1.6%   3.7KiB             std core::slice::sort::recurse
0.1%   1.6%   3.7KiB             std gimli::read::rnglists::RngListIter<R>::next
0.1%   1.4%   3.3KiB xentrace_parser xentrace_parser::xentrace_parse
0.1%   1.4%   3.2KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::elf::<impl std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::...
0.1%   1.3%   3.1KiB             std rustc_demangle::demangle
0.1%   1.3%   2.9KiB xentrace_parser alloc::slice::merge_sort
0.1%   1.2%   2.8KiB             std <rustc_demangle::legacy::Demangle as core::fmt::Display>::fmt
0.1%   1.0%   2.3KiB             std gimli::read::line::parse_attribute
0.1%   0.9%   2.1KiB             std core::str::count::do_count_chars
0.0%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std rustc_demangle::v0::Printer::print_const
0.0%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std hashbrown::raw::RawTable<T,A>::reserve_rehash
0.0%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std rustc_demangle::v0::Printer::print_path
3.1%  51.5% 118.6KiB                 And 566 smaller methods. Use -n N to show more.
6.1% 100.0% 230.3KiB                 .text section size, the file size is 3.7MiB
```

And in **Fedora**:

```bash
$ toolbox run cargo bloat --release
File  .text     Size           Crate Name
 4.7%   8.6%  19.8KiB             std addr2line::ResDwarf<R>::parse
 4.3%   7.9%  18.2KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::resolve::{{closure}}
 2.3%   4.2%   9.6KiB             std addr2line::ResUnit<R>::parse_lines
 2.0%   3.7%   8.5KiB             std miniz_oxide::inflate::core::decompress
 1.4%   2.6%   5.9KiB             std gimli::read::abbrev::Abbreviations::insert
 1.1%   1.9%   4.5KiB             std gimli::read::unit::parse_attribute
 0.9%   1.7%   4.0KiB             std addr2line::function::Function<R>::parse_children
 0.9%   1.7%   3.9KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::Context::new
 0.9%   1.6%   3.7KiB             std core::slice::sort::recurse
 0.9%   1.6%   3.7KiB             std gimli::read::rnglists::RngListIter<R>::next
 0.8%   1.4%   3.3KiB xentrace_parser xentrace_parser::xentrace_parse
 0.8%   1.4%   3.2KiB             std std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli::elf::<impl std::backtrace_rs::symbolize::gimli:...
 0.7%   1.3%   3.1KiB             std rustc_demangle::demangle
 0.7%   1.3%   2.9KiB xentrace_parser alloc::slice::merge_sort
 0.7%   1.2%   2.8KiB             std <rustc_demangle::legacy::Demangle as core::fmt::Display>::fmt
 0.5%   1.0%   2.3KiB             std gimli::read::line::parse_attribute
 0.5%   0.9%   2.1KiB             std core::str::count::do_count_chars
 0.4%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std rustc_demangle::v0::Printer::print_const
 0.4%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std hashbrown::raw::RawTable<T,A>::reserve_rehash
 0.4%   0.8%   1.8KiB             std rustc_demangle::v0::Printer::print_path
28.3%  51.5% 118.7KiB                 And 568 smaller methods. Use -n N to show more.
55.0% 100.0% 230.5KiB                 .text section size, the file size is 418.9KiB
```

They are virtually identical except for the first column of percentages.

Comment: I don't know the reason, but you could try to find out by yourself with `cargo bloat` and `strip`ing to see what parts of the binary are large.

Comment: How did you install `rust` and `cargo` in both environments? If using the official packages, it's possible that Fedora changed some settings from the Rust defaults…

Comment: @Jmb I've installed it with `rustup` on Arch, and `rustc` + `cargo` using the package manager in Fedora

Comment: Looks like the Fedora installed versions strip the binaries by default. You can also compare the output of `readelf -S`, which will probably include the `.debug_*` sections on Arch and not on Fedora.

Comment: @Jmb you're right!